# How to get the path where the file is upload from the system - Supported browser IE?

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I want to print the file path where it is upload. I am using IE 11. Can anyone let me know how to get the file path when it is uploaded from servlet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Answer (score 0):

@NaredraKumar
I don't think you can find the system path of file upload from browser, even if you got it should be the fake path or temp path.